# Is there a way to invoke a Spotlight search from another Mac app?

Tags: spotlight, url

I'd like to be able to do something like `spotlight://tag:Red` from other apps to open a Spotlight search in Finder. Is it possible, somehow?

EDIT:

I found and tried [AppleScripts/AppleScript applet for Spotlight URI handler.applescript at master · nathan-artist/AppleScripts](https://github.com/nathan-artist/AppleScripts/blob/master/AppleScript%20applet%20for%20Spotlight%20URI%20handler.applescript), but unfortunately I can't get it to work on my macOS 12.4.

Comment: This may help: https://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/search-for-files-by-keyword-in-spotlight-on-macos/

Comment: Mmm, no, actually it doesn't.

Comment: Can you explain the process a bit more?  Do you just want a shortcut for "Switch to Finder and Command F"...? Or do you want one specific search criteria to be triggered from other apps? Or do you want the criteria to vary? Which apps?

Comment: Yes @benwiggy, of course! (Thanks for your interest!)

In particular in Obsidian, I'd like to run a command that opens Spotlight in Finder, and run a search specified programmatically. E.g., `spotlight://tag:Red` should search for all files with tag `Red`, `spotlight://.pdf` all the pdf files, etc.

Comment: So really, you just want an automated process to switch to the Finder, and access a saved search.